# How do I send an email to multiple recipients using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp

I have a sendmail funciton that works for one recipient. If I pass something like "email1@test.com;email2@test.com" in ToEmail then I get an error that says ; not allowed in message header. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my SendMail function:

```
 Public Function SendMail(ByVal ToEmail As String, ByVal FromEmail As String, ByVal Subject As String, ByVal Body As String, Optional ByVal bccEmail As String = "", Optional ByVal bIsHTML As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim msgMail As New MailMessage(FromEmail, ToEmail, Subject, Body)
        msgMail.IsBodyHtml = bIsHTML
        If bccEmail <> "" Then
            msgMail.Bcc.Add(bccEmail)
        End If
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient
            smtp.Host = "myServer"

        smtp.Send(msgMail)
        SendMail = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        DoTrace(ex.Source, ex.Message)
        SendMail = False
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The addresses need to be separated with commas, not semicolons.

Comment: +1 Wish I had posted this answer first before double checking :).

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `To` property which is a `MailAddressCollection`, and call the `Add()` method to add the email addresses individually.

If you're passing your email addresses into your function as a semi-colon separated list, then just do a `String.Split()` on them, and add them into the `To` property in an iteration loop.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using MailMergeLib
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/MailMergeLib.aspx

It also fixes a bunch of bugs in the .NET mail classes.

Answer (score 0):

change your toEmail from string to `MailAddressCollection` and you are done